# How to delete a pattern matching and the rest of the line in a file using Perl

Tags: perl

I'm a new programmer in Perl and i would like to find a pattern in a file and delete it with the rest of the line. For example,

"input file"

```
>hsa-let-7a-5p MIMAT0000062 Homo sapiens let-7a-5p
UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUU
>hsa-let-7a-3p MIMAT0004481 Homo sapiens let-7a-3p
CUAUACAAUCUACUGUCUUUC
>hsa-let-7a-2-3p MIMAT0010195 Homo sapiens let-7a-2-3p
CUGUACAGCCUCCUAGCUUUCC
>hsa-let-7b-5p MIMAT0000063 Homo sapiens let-7b-5p
UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUGUGGUU
```

"desired output file"

```
>hsa-let-7a-5p MIMAT0000062 
UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUU
>hsa-let-7a-3p MIMAT0004481 
CUAUACAAUCUACUGUCUUUC
>hsa-let-7a-2-3p MIMAT0010195 
CUGUACAGCCUCCUAGCUUUCC
>hsa-let-7b-5p MIMAT0000063 
UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUGUGGUU
```

I want to find the string "Homo sapiens" and delete it as well as the rest of the line.

I write the following code but it is not functional

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $find = "Homo sapiens"; #string for searching
open (FILE1, "input.fasta") || die "Cannot open the file!"; #open for reading
open (FILE2, ">>output.fasta") || die "Cannot open the file!"; #open for writing

while (my $line = <FILE1>){
        if ($line =~ /$find/){
                print FILE2 $line;
                print FILE2 scalar <FILE1>;
        }
}                

close(FILE1);
close(FILE2);

exit;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The majority of the Linux world has a fascination with one-line programs, so here is a one-line solution that does as you ask

```
perl -pe's/\s*Homo Sapiens.*//i' input.txt
```

It will make the changes that you describe and send the result to STDOUT.

If you want to write the altered text to a new file then simply redirect the output, with something like

```
perl -pe's/\s*Homo Sapiens.*//i' input.txt > fixed.txt
```

**output**

```
>hsa-let-7a-5p MIMAT0000062
UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUU
>hsa-let-7a-3p MIMAT0004481
CUAUACAAUCUACUGUCUUUC
>hsa-let-7a-2-3p MIMAT0010195
CUGUACAGCCUCCUAGCUUUCC
>hsa-let-7b-5p MIMAT0000063
UGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUGUGGUU
```

If you are not one of those people and you need help to write the equivalent Perl program then please ask.

---

**Update**

An equivalent program would look like this. I've called it `sapiens.pl`. You would run it from the command line with the input file as a parameter, such as

```
sapiens.pl input.txt > fixed.txt
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $remove = 'Homo sapiens';

while (<>) {
    s/\s*$remove.*//i;
    print;
}
```

Comment: Is the `\s*` necessary?

Comment: Or maybe `perl -ne 'print unless /Homo Sapiens/'` -- depends on if the questioner wants blank lines or deleted lines.

Comment: @JimDavis: The question says what they wanted

Comment: @Floegipoky: The leading `\s*` removes any whitespace preceding the `Homo sapiens`. There may not be any, but there is in the OP's example and I think it's dreadful programming to generate output with trailing whitespace before the newlines.

Comment: @Borodin: I misinterpreted "rest of the line"; my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace your `while` loop with the following.

```
while (<FILE1>){
    s/$find.*//;
    print FILE2 $line;
}
```

I loaded the line into the default variable by not specifically assigning it to any other variable, and then applied the substitution operator to it.  I am substituting your variable find any any characters that come after it in the line with the empty string.  We don't need to check if the substitution worked.  If it did, then we removed the unwanted characters;  If not, then we want the entire line.